# donut shaped bitmap in android java

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-bitmap

i have an urge to achieve a bitmap transformation in android which cut out a donut shaped image from the source

here is an example

[image].

here is a transformation which can give a circular bitmap

```
int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());
int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
```

i dont know how to proceed further. please help

Comment: What an odd urge.

Comment: Have you seen: [Porter-Duff mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode)

Comment: @MorrisonChang i see. this can surly help. thank you. would be even nice if you have some code ?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch hehe. i m writing a music player. in that i m trying to create a cassette image from original image

Comment: I don't have code. But I have [dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Disc_Digital_Audio#/media/File:Basic_Illustration_and_mesures_of_a_CD.png).